# Append JSON data at a specific index

Tags: javascript-objects

I'm trying to append the JSON data at a specific index but it's not working. The JSON data is-

a = {resourceTypeId: "tmf.resourceTypes.TmfServiceInterface", transitions: [2], states: null}

**There are 2 arrays in transitions**

**transitions: [2]**

*0: {…}
stateFrom: "initial"
stateTo: "feasibilityChecked"
name: "checkFeasibility"
operationName: "checkServiceFeasibility"*

*1: {…}
stateFrom: "initial"
stateTo: "designed"
name: "design"
operationName: "designService"*

I'm trying to append the 3rd array in transitions

b = {
"name": "deleteaaa",
"operationName": "Serviceaa",
"stateFrom": "test",
"stateTo": "test"
}

I've tried this-

c = a.transitions.concat(b)

It's adding the 3rd array in transitions but not getting Other data like resourceTypeId: "tmf.resourceTypes.TmfServiceInterface" and states: null

The expected data should be after merging b into a

**c = {resourceTypeId: "tmf.resourceTypes.TmfServiceInterface", *transitions: [3]*, states: null}**

Pls, assist.

Answer (score 0):

you maybe want this

a.transitions = a.transitions.concat(b)

```js
var a = {
    "resourceTypeId": "tmf.resourceTypes.TmfServiceInterface",
    "transitions": [
        {
            "stateFrom": "initial",
            "stateTo": "feasibilityChecked",
            "name": "checkFeasibility",
            "operationName": "checkServiceFeasibility"
        },
        {
            "stateFrom": "initial",
            "stateTo": "designed",
            "name": "design",
            "operationName": "designService"
        },
        {
            "name": "deleteaaa",
            "operationName": "Serviceaa",
            "stateFrom": "test",
            "stateTo": "test"
        }
    ],
    "states": null
}

var b = {
    "name": "deleteaaa",
    "operationName": "Serviceaa",
    "stateFrom": "test",
    "stateTo": "test"
}

a.transitions = a.transitions.concat(b)

console.log(a)
```

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHRyP.png)

Comment: 2. Can you provide some more explanation on what does your code do?